# What is the minimum disk space requirement for root and swap?

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, root

I am new in Ubuntu. I going to install Ubuntu 16.04 in my PC. How much minimum disk space should I assign to root ans swap? When I install any software where is it stored actually? I have 4GB RAM and a 500GB HDD.

Comment: A 2 GB swap should be more than enough. How much storage space do you have?

Comment: Then I would give Ubuntu a root partition size of 20-40 GB. Its really just preference.

Comment: Do you wish to use hibernate?

Comment: Root: 20 GB, Swap: 4 GB. Software is stored on the home or data partition.

Answer (score 1):

A very general principle that I use is an equal amount of swap as you have in RAM.  So, as I see you have 4GB of RAM, I would mark down 4GB of swap.  As to hard disk space, if you are not storing any personal files on it, you have plenty with 15GB.

That's coming from a hard user who does a fair amount of video production and photo editing: if you're a somewhat less aggressive user on your resources, you would be fine with half as much swap.

I see that you have a 500GB HD: I would recommend 8GB of swap (too much can't hurt) and the rest partitioned off as your root partition.  You'll have plenty of space for some personal files as well.

Comment: Well, the "equivalent to RAM" rule with swap is generally antiquated. 2GB of swap should be plenty, unless OP wants to use hibernate. Even then, 4GB swap is plenty.

Comment: Hmm, I would beg to differ, but it really depends what you're doing.  I frequently top 4GB of swap used on my system with 8GB of ram. @patrickyi.

Comment: @Rana Then I would use 2-4 GB swap.

Comment: @anonymous2 OP probably has a consumer machine, given the 500 GB HDD and measly 4GB RAM. I don't think he's doing work intensive-enough to top even 2 GB swap.